# Expected difference from mean: is it always zero?

Tags: probability-theory

The quantity
$$
\mathbf{E}(x-\mu)=\int (x-\mu)P(x) dx
$$
is equal to zero for symmetric probability density functions. What about the others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\mu = \mathbb{E}[X]$, then

$$
\mathbb{E}[X - \mu] = \mathbb{E}[X] - \mathbb{E}[\mu] = \mathbb{E}[X] - \mu = \mu - \mu = 0
$$

regardless of the skewness of $X$

Answer (score 1):

Yeah just expand it out, assuming $\mu = E[X]$, use linearity of expected value:

$$E(x-\mu) = E[x] - E[\mu] = \int xP(x) dx - \int \mu P(x)dx$$

The first integral is the expected value by definition and the second integral can take out the constant $\mu$

$$= E[X] - \mu \int P(x) dx$$

And since $\int P(x) dx = 1$ for any pdf,

$$= \mu - \mu(1) = \mu - \mu =  0$$